# Creating a Jax-WS webservice

Tags: java, web-services

I am new to webservice. I need to create a JAX-WS webservice to return some user details.
I know how to create a web service which can return primitive types like String,int. But I need to create web service to return a Map. The MAP may contain a user defined class object. 
I searched in google, but I am not getting a clear example for this.
Can anyone please post an example of JAX-WS webservice returning a Map,List.. or any links from where I can refer.
I tried creating one, but it is not working properly. Below is the code :

LoginMethodsImpl.java

```
 @WebService
        public interface LoginMethods {

            public Map authenicateUser(@WebParam(name="mailId")String mailId,
                    @WebParam(name="password")String password);
        }
```

LoginMethodsImpl.java

```
@WebService(endpointInterface="com.Nagesh.AndroidLoginExample.src.LoginMethods",
    portName="LoginWSPort",
    serviceName="LoginService")
    public class LoginMethodsImpl implements LoginMethods{
      @Override
        public Map<String,Object> authenicateUser(String mailId,String password) {
            Map<String,Object>userDetailsMap=new HashMap<String,Object>();
            con=new DBConnection().getDBConnection();
            stmt=con.prepareStatement(USER_LOGIN_SQL);
            stmt.setString(1, mailId);
            rs=stmt.executeQuery();
            while(rs.next()){
                String pwd=rs.getString(2);
                if(pwd.equals(password))
                {
                    userDetailsMap.put("STAT","SUCCESS");
                    userDetailsMap.put("CUST_ID", rs.getInt(1));
                    userDetailsMap.put("EMAILID", rs.getString(2));
                    userDetailsMap.put("NAME", rs.getString(4));
                    userDetailsMap.put("PHONE", rs.getString(5));
                }
                else
                    userDetailsMap.put("STAT", "FAILED");
            }
            return userDetailsMap;
        }
    }
```

Other files in My Webservice are :

```
sun-jaxws.xml
web.xml
```

I created a JAXB class using the WSGEN tool in the process of creating the webservice.
    Exception I am getting

```
failed to parse runtime descriptor: javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: class com.Nagesh.AndroidLoginExample.src.jaxws.AuthenicateUserResponse do not have a property of the name return
javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: class com.Nagesh.AndroidLoginExample.src.jaxws.AuthenicateUserResponse do not have a property of the name return
    at com.sun.xml.ws.server.sei.EndpointResponseMessageBuilder$DocLit.<init>(EndpointResponseMessageBuilder.java:258)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.server.sei.TieHandler.createResponseMessageBuilder(TieHandler.java:212)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.server.sei.TieHandler.<init>(TieHandler.java:117)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.db.DatabindingImpl.<init>(DatabindingImpl.java:116)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.db.DatabindingProviderImpl.create(DatabindingProviderImpl.java:74)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.db.DatabindingProviderImpl.create(DatabindingProviderImpl.java:58)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.db.DatabindingFactoryImpl.createRuntime(DatabindingFactoryImpl.java:120)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.server.EndpointFactory.createSEIModel(EndpointFactory.java:521)
```

Note : I am creating web service for the first time.

Comment: do you mean jax-rs ?

Comment: @JayMar :  yes. I think that is the one. I created it seeing an tutorial in youtube with title : **Creating Java web service using jax-ws and deploying on tomcat server**.

Comment: jax-ws Hello world example http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-ws/jax-ws-hello-world-example/

Comment: @JayMar : I have created a simple WS to return primitive types. I want to create a WS returning Map Objects.